# How to solve issues related to java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedPropertyResolver in spring boot 2.1.3.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have been developing a social login system using the guidance from the site mentioned below:
http://littlebigextra.com/part-1-authorising-user-using-spring-social-google-facebook-and-linkedin-and-spring-security/

I have done everything as guidance. However, when i try to build project i got an error :
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedPropertyResolver

Can soneone help to sort out this issue in spring boot (2.1.3.RELEASED)

My pom.xml file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>springboot.sociallogin</groupId>
    <artifactId>socialspringbootlogin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>socialspringbootlogin</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot and social login</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--begin of dependency for spring social-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-config</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-google</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-linkedin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--end of dependency for spring social-->
        <!--begin of dependency for thymeleaf-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
            <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>                               
        </dependency>
        <!--end of dependency for thymeleaf-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
            <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
         <optional>true</optional>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
    <!--    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>alfresco-public</id>
            <url>https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>-->

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Stop mixing jars from different versions. You are mixing 2.1.3 and 1.5.2 jars, never do things like that as stuff will break. The guide you are following is out-dated as login like that isn't supported anymore (Spring Social is dead/in maintenance mode) in favor of using OAuth2 through Spring Security.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion M. Deinum. Can you suggest me some resources for  login with social medias and spring boot (including Oauth2). I would be grateful.

Comment: The spring security reference guide on the matter.